# How to override operator and (&&) for generic predicate in swift?

Tags: swift

I have a class that has information about data filtering before this data. I want to save the filtering predicate to use it in the future stage when data will be given. The filtering predicate is a combination of other predicates, and I found that it will be useful to create the function for combining them as I will need.

```
func and<T>(_ lth: @escaping (T) -> Bool,
            _ rth: @escaping (T) -> Bool) -> (T) -> Bool {

    return { o in lth(o) && rth(o) }
}
```

Example of use:

```
func xIsNot(_ x: Int) -> (Int, Int) -> Bool {
    return { x1, _ in x != x1 }
}

func yIsNot(_ y: Int) -> (Int, Int) -> Bool {
    return { _, y1 in y != y1 }
}

let predicate = someCondition
    ? and(and(xIsNot(7), xIsNot(8)), yIsNot(9))
    : and(xIsNot(2), yIsNot(3))

let points: [(Int, Int)] = ...
let actualPoints = points.filter(predicate)
```

It works fine but hasn't good readability. The following looks much better:

```
let predicate = someCondition
    ? xIsNot(7) && xIsNot(8) && yIsNot(9)
    : xIsNot(2) && yIsNot(3)
```

Is it possible to override operator `&&` to replace `and`? How?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may try this :

```
infix operator &&& : AdditionPrecedence
func &&&<T>(_ lth: @escaping (T) -> Bool,
        _ rth: @escaping (T) -> Bool) -> (T) -> Bool {
return { x in lth(x) && rth(x) }
}

let predicate = true
? xIsNot(7) &&& xIsNot(8) &&& yIsNot(9)
: xIsNot(2) &&& yIsNot(3)

let points: [(Int, Int)] = [(1,2),(7,3)]
let actualPoints = points.filter(predicate)
```

The following && is also working.

```
infix operator && : AdditionPrecedence
func &&<T>(_ lth: @escaping (T) -> Bool,
        _ rth: @escaping (T) -> Bool) -> (T) -> Bool {
return { x in lth(x) && rth(x) }
}

let predicate = true
? xIsNot(7) && xIsNot(8) && yIsNot(9)
: xIsNot(2) && yIsNot(3)
```

Comment: Fine. As I understand, the overriding of && is impossible for the described situation. Is my understanding correct?

Comment: Yes, but it would confuse with `lth(x) && rth(x)` by reading, although not the compiler.

Comment: I think it is not a big problem because `lth(x)` and `rth(x)` are Bools and function signature declares that operator is for `(T) -> Bool`.

Comment: I agree. You can pick which one you like.

Comment: However, I want to mark your answer as correct but can't do it for the current form yet. Can you add some additional description into your answer about that overriding of && is possible too, please?